# Do I need to pay Ryanair checked baggage fee separately on the return trip?

Tags: uk, fees-and-charges, ryanair

I've paid the checked baggage fee at the airport on the outbound trip. The Ryanair Android app doesn't tell me anywhere whether I can bring a checked bag on the return trip. Do I have to pay again? Can't seem to find this information clearly stated anywhere on their website.

**Edit:** when I try to add a bag, here's what I see:

[image]

Note "You have purchased one bag"; given that this is the button I click to add a bag to the return trip, this text very much seems to imply that I don't need to pay again. Or do I?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Baggage fees are always per check-in. It is valid for multiple legs when you fly them in sequence, but when you get your baggage back, you're done, and next check-in costs again.

Comment: Ryanair do not do "multiple legs". Each leg is a separate journey and no baggage will be checked through.

Comment: Well I've paid for my bag, and now the website says "You have purchased 2 bags". I think you may be mistaken.